# How to count in a range with .Find() function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count, range

I have the following Excel Worksheet

[image]

With the following `.Find()` function I found the value that I need and the cell.

```
Dim finalResult as Range
Dim finalValue as String
Dim headValue as string

finalValue = "Banana"
headValue = "Food"

Set finalResult = Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1:A20").Find(finalValue, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=headValue)
```

My question is: Knowing the **Start = Food** and the **End = Banana** of the range, how do I count how many cells there are between?

Thank you

Comment: 'finalResult.Row (for Banana) - finalResult.Row (for Food)`... It is good to declare two specific variables: `finalFood` and `finalBanana`, for instance. Or use `CountA` for the range of the two obtain cell ranges.

Comment: What type of declaration should I do? 
`Dim finalCount as Integer` ` finalCount = finalResult.Row - finalValue` ?

Comment: One could also use `Application.Match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, please. There are more methods to find your cells, but I will use the one you look to prefer:

```
Sub testFindRange()
 Dim finalResFood As Range, finalResBanana As Range
 Dim finalValue As String, headValue As String, sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = Worksheets("mySheet")' Having more workbooks open, it would be good to define it using the workbook where it belongs, too.

 finalValue = "Banana"
 headValue = "Food"

 Set finalResBanana = sh.Range("A1:A20").Find(finalValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
 Set finalResFood = sh.Range("A1:A20").Find(headValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
 Debug.Print finalResBanana.row - finalResFood.row
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that `Range.Find` would be the more common and prefered method +. However, two remarks: `xlWhole` parameter seems required and a test for `Is Not Nothing`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple options really:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A:A")
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

'-------------------------------------
'Option 1: Range.Object
Set rng1 = rng.Find("Food", Lookat:=xlWhole)
Set rng2 = rng.Find("Banana", Lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rng2.Row - rng1.Row
End If

'-------------------------------------
'Option 2: Application.Match
With Application
    rw1 = .Match("Food", rng, 0)
    rw2 = .Match("Banana", rng, 0)
    If IsError(rw1) = False And IsError(rw2) = False Then
        Debug.Print rw2 - rw1
    End If
End With

'-------------------------------------
'Option 3: xlDown
Set rng1 = rng.Find("Food", Lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rng1(rng1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row - rng1.Row
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are sure about the white line under "Banana", the advantage of option 3 would be that you don't need the last value under "Food" category @ChangeWorld.

Comment: Yes I'm sure about the white line under "Banana", I'm trying option 3 that seems very light also-

Comment: Helpful for everybody to discover that there are *more roads leading to Rome* ..+)